# Принцип работы Vuforia?

Tags: unity3d, книги, документация, vuforia

Гугл постоянно выдает ссылки на восторженные отзывы об использовании фреймворка  vuforia и стартовые мануалы. Но это коммерческий продукт, с ограниченным доступом для разработчиков. 
Меня это не устраивает. Мне интересно как это работает, какие алгоритмы применяются для определения угла под которым смотрят на объект/картинку. Есть ли где-то возможность почитать об этом, желательно в доступной стилистике. Мне бы хотя бы принцип понять, прежде чем в дебри зарываться.

Спасибо!